# Feet not moving with rest of rig

Tags: bones

I can't get the feet to move with the rig when I move it in pose mode using the main torso bone, or pelvis, ect that moves the whole rig at once. I know this is a very basic problem but I've tried to parent the leg bones in different ways and can't seem to get it to work. Also I don't know what is going on with all the connection lines or dotted lines, but that's beside the point.

[image: bones]

[image: result]

Comment: If that's a rigify generated rig, it's because you have the rig's feet in IK mode.  If you want them to move with the torso you have to switch to FK mode.

Comment: Click the 'Root' button in the N-panel as seen in the first screenshot. Then you will see the root control bone. Use it to move the whole model.

Comment: Thanks, both were right.